# Time-based rotation of Docker logs

Tags: docker, logging, logrotate, docker-swarm, log-rotation

We are running a stack of Docker Swarm services and, according to our Privacy Policy, we have to keep logs only for the last 6 months, but no older. I was trying to achieve it through different logging drivers, but all of them (AFAIK) work only with max file-size, but not with times/dates.

The one solution that I came up with: use `json-file` logging driver and then setup `logrotate.d` with `rotate 180` and `daily` options.

The problem, however, is that `json-file` logging driver doesn't disable standard Docker logging (I mean `docker logs -f ...` or `docker service logs -f ...`) which uses some internal Docker storage for logs, as per documentation:

> Only the `json-file` and `journald` drivers make the logs available directly from `docker-compose up` and `docker-compose logs`. Using any other driver does not print any logs.

In this case, the rotation will work for `json-file` logs, but the "internal" logs will be still kept longer.

So, I wonder, how can one achieve time-based Docker log rotation?